# Static 'hover-state' after click? For a section based site

Tags: jquery, css, hover, pageload

I have a section based website (tabbed navigation) where content is loaded into a container. I have a couple inner tabbed navigation as well that behave the same. My issue is that users can't see what section they are in and I wanted to have the hover state keep until another link is clicked in the same navigation.

I don't think I have any code that will be useful to anyone as I don't have any of this created yet. Please let me know if you need anything - thanks!

Comment: We need something outlining the core principal of this. You need to look at your issues objectively, such as, 'how do I do X and make Y happen in javascript?'..This way, we can help you to reach objectives. As it stands this isn't a good fit for our Q&A format...

Answer (score 1):

*I agree with the comment mentioned above
But I think I have some idea of what you are referring to*.

You should have a CSS class **.active** which contains the same style as the hover state.

You can then use jQuery to **addClass** when selected and **removeClass** so no other tabs have this active class.

check here http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Also you can check here as a reference for tabs http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs